# Is it possible to modify Post Visibility options text in the WordPress post.php admin screen?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'd like to edit the text that comes up in the modal under Visibility -> <current post visibility status Public|Private|Password Protected>.

For example, instead of Public -> Visible to everyone, I'd like it to say something like "Visible to subscribers".

I know I can edit *editor.js*, but would like to avoid editing core files. I've looked through the [Block Editor Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/), specifically the [Block Controls: Block Toolbar and Settings Sidebar](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/block-controls-toolbar-and-sidebar/) page but I don't see any way to edit the visibilityOptions const.

Currently, I've hacked it using MutationObserver right now, but I'm hoping there's a "right" way to do this. The only other option I see right now is to hide the default block and create an entirely new one.

[image: wordpress post visibility modal]

Comment: I don't think there is a "right" way to do it - since WP doesn't have a filter/hook or anything to change the JS that creates the fields. I say, if what you have works for you, use it.

Comment: Thanks, @disinfor. I haven't modified WordPress much since they added all the Gutenberg stuff and wasn't sure if the extensibility was carried through. Sounds like it hasn't been.